# Using whereRaw() and orWhereRaw() with Join in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am writing a code like this:-

```
$results = User::select('users.id','users.user_type','users.status','homechef_details.user_id','homechef_details.address1','homechef_details.name','homechef_details.updated_rating')
        ->join('homechef_details', function($query) use ($rating,$keyword) {
            $query->on('users.id', '=', 'homechef_details.user_id');
            $query->where('users.status','=',1);
            if(isset($rating) && !empty($rating)) 
            {
                if(count($rating)==1)
                    $query->whereRaw('FLOOR(homechef_details.updated_rating) = '.$rating[0]);
                else if(count($rating)>1)
                {
                    $query->where(function($q) use($rating)
                    {
                        $q->whereRaw('FLOOR(homechef_details.updated_rating) = '.$rating[0]);
                        for($r = 1; $r < count($rating); $r++)
                        {
                           $q->orWhereRaw('FLOOR(homechef_details.updated_rating) = '.$rating[$r]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        })->get();
```

I need to check the floor value of the column value in the where clause. I am getting this error:-

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereRaw()
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the JoinClause class doesn't have a method for raw queries, i suggest you try soemthing like

```
$results = User::select('users.id','users.user_type','users.status','homechef_details.user_id','homechef_details.address1','homechef_details.name','homechef_details.updated_rating')
        ->join('homechef_details','users.id', '=', 'homechef_details.user_id')->where('users.status','=',1);
            if(isset($rating) && !empty($rating)) 
            {
                if(count($rating)==1)
                   $results = $results->whereRaw('FLOOR(homechef_details.updated_rating) = '.$rating[0]);
                else if(count($rating)>1)
                {
                   $results = $results->where(function($q) use($rating)
                    {
                        $q->whereRaw('FLOOR(homechef_details.updated_rating) = '.$rating[0]);
                        for($r = 1; $r < count($rating); $r++)
                        {
                           $q->orWhereRaw('FLOOR(homechef_details.updated_rating) = '.$rating[$r]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
 $results = $results->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That acted like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside closure, `$query` is instance of `JoinClause` and it does not have `whereRaw()` methods.

As alternative to madalinivascu's answer, you can use `DB::raw()` to construct raw SQL inside closure.