# Laravel orWhereRaw with join

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I'm trying to get the below query working. The latest error I'm getting is `Object of class Closure could not be converted to string`.

I was reading that in older versions of Laravel (5.2), that: `$query` is instance of `JoinClause` and it does not have `whereRaw()` methods.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/47672758/4113027)

How can I write this query such that it works?

```
$results = DB::table('statement_transactions AS st')
            ->join('quickbooks_transactions AS qt', function ($join) {
                $join->on('st.transaction_date', '=', 'qt.transaction_date');
                $join->on('st.transaction_type_id', '=', 'qt.transaction_type_id');
                $join->on('st.original_amount', '=', 'qt.original_amount');
                $join->on('st.balance', '=', 'qt.balance');
            })
            ->where('st.statement_id', $this->statement->id)
            ->where('st.has_match', 0)
            ->where('st.has_partial_match', 0)
            ->whereNull('st.quickbooks_transaction_id')
            ->orWhereRaw(function ($query) {
                $query->whereRaw("LEFT(REPLACE(st.invoice_nbr, '-', ''), 5) = LEFT(REPLACE(qt.invoice_nbr, '-', ''), 5)")
                    ->whereRaw("RIGHT(REPLACE(st.invoice_nbr, '-', ''), 5) = RIGHT(REPLACE(qt.invoice_nbr, '-', ''), 5)");
            })
            ->select('st.id AS statement_transaction_id', 'qt.id AS quickbooks_transaction_id')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
->orWhereRaw(function ($query) {
    $query->whereRaw("LEFT(REPLACE(st.invoice_nbr, '-', ''), 5) = LEFT(REPLACE(qt.invoice_nbr, '-', ''), 5)")
    ->whereRaw("RIGHT(REPLACE(st.invoice_nbr, '-', ''), 5) = RIGHT(REPLACE(qt.invoice_nbr, '-', ''), 5)");
})
```

`orWhereRaw()` expects one argument, a string. Instead, you're passing it a closure (i.e. your `function ($query) { ... }`).

You need to change `orWhereRaw` to `orWhere`, which does accept a closure.